# If $X$ is locally path connected then the components and the path components are the same

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Hi i am reading Topology by Munkres and there in theorem 25.5 i have two doubts.In the proof it says that

> Since $P$ is connected, $P\subset C$.

Then at another line it says

> each of them necessarily lies in $C$.

My doubts are as following:

1. How does P is connected imply $P\subset C$?
2. How does each of them lies necessarily in $C$?
3. Why are we taking the union of all path components of $X$ that are different from $P$ and intersect $C$?

For reference i am attaching the screenshot of the theorem's proof where i have highlighted the part where the above quoted statements are given.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every path-connected set is connected. $P$ is the path component containing $x$, so $P$ is a connected set containing $x$. $C$, the component containing $x$, is the union of all connected sets containing $x$, so $P\subseteq C$.

Suppose that $P_0$ is a path component of $X$ that intersects $C$. Then $C\cup P_0$ is connected, so it is a connected set containing $x$ and is therefore contained in $C$, the largest connected set containing $x$. That is, $P_0\subseteq C$ for each path component of $X$ that intersects $C$, and $Q$ is the union of some of those path components, so $Q\subseteq C$.

The answer to your third question is implicit in the final paragraph of the proof. We’ve supposed that $P\subsetneqq C$ in order to get a contradiction. Showing that $C$ is not connected would give us a contradiction, since by definition the component $C$ **is** connected. And it turns out that $P$ and $Q$ give us a separation of $C$ and therefore give us the desired contradiction.

It may help if I expand that last paragraph a bit. Every point of $C$ lies in a unique path component of $X$ that intersects $C$. Either that path component is $P$, or it is a path component of $X$ that intersects $C$ but is not $P$. Thus, every point of $C$ is either in $P$ or in $Q$, and we’ve just seen that $P\cup Q\subseteq C$, so in fact $P\cup Q=C$, and of course $P\cap Q=\varnothing$. The final step is to use the hypothesis that $X$ is locally path-connected, which implies that each path component is open. In particular, $P$ is open, and $Q$, which is a union of path components, is also open. Thus, $C$ is the union of the disjoint, non-empty open sets $P$ and $Q$ and is therefore not connected — and there’s the desired contradiction showing that $P$ cannot be a proper subset of $C$ after all: it must be all of $C$.

Comment: Ok i have two doubts.First is that how every point of C Lies in a unique path component of X that intersects C as you've written in the first line of your 3rd paragraph.My second doubt is that you've shown $P\cup C=C$ that i understand but then wrote in line 6 of 3rd para that  C is the union of $P$ and $Q$ so how did we get $P\cup Q=C$ from $P\cup C=C$? Thanks

Comment: @JasonLiam: Every point of $X$ lies in a unique path component. If the point is in $C$, then obviously that path component must intersect $C$, since the point $x$ is in the intersection. Your second question is the result of a typo on my part: I wrote $C$ several times where I should have written $Q$. It’s fixed now.

Comment: Ok i think there is one more typo at line 3 of 3rd paragraph where you've written is either in $P$ or in$C$ while it should be is either in $P$ or in $Q$ . I have 2 more doubts:first is that how is $P\cap Q=\varnothing$? and second doubt is you've written if the point is in $C$ then obviously that path component must intersect $C$ since the point x is in the intersection. So are you talking about the path component P that is unique and contains x?

Comment: @JasonLiam: Yep, I missed the one. $Q$ is the union of path components that are different from $P$; the path components of a space are pairwise disjoint, so the ones that are different from $P$ are automatically disjoint from $P$, and so is $Q$, their union. Yes, I was talking about the unique path component containing $x$.